# Sublime Text: How to select an everything contained in an HTML element?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, emmet

I'm running Sublime Text 2 on OS X.

```
<table>
 ...
</table>
```

If my cursor is at the beginning of the opening `table` tag is it possible to automatically select *everything* down to (and including) the ending tag? I have the [Emmet plugin](http://emmet.io/) installed but can't figure out if this is possible.

Using Emmet ⌘+⇧+k selects both the beginning and ending tag but *not* the text in between those tags (which is my goal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> in Windows. It should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in OS X.

[Emmet Documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/match-pair/)

Comment: ⌘+, in OS X opens Sublime's preferences (as it does in all OS X apps).